# javascript how to display multiple options by user with while statement and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I need to make a while loop and every time I do it it seems to freeze my browser so it must not be closing correctly.  I am making a resume and I want the user to select a number, 1-5 and then it display that many of my previous job duties from my array that I've created. I need to create a variable and set it equal to the inputted value minus 1. Create a while loop that runs while the variable (that represents the index value that I need to print) is greater than or equal to the minimum array value. Have the innerHTML of some element within my page be replaced with the array value that corresponds to the index number printed.  This is what I have in the javascript function.

```js
function duties() {
    var subskill = ["Make Beautiful Sandwiches","Customer Service Skills", "Count Register", "Upsell", "Manage"];

    var numduty = parseFloat(document.getElementById('numduties').value);
    var numdutfinal = numduty - 1;
    var list = "";

    while (numdutfinal <= numduty ){
        list= list+numdutfinal;
        numdutfinal--;
    }
    document.getElementById('duty1').innerHTML = subskill[list]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your decrementing `numdutfinal`, and your while loop is set to exit once it becomes greater than `numduty`, it's just getting farther and farther away from `numduty` for each run.

for example, if `numduty` starts as 5, and `numdutfinal` is 4, then after the first run through the loop, `numdutfinal` becomes 3, etc, never becoming greater than 5.

edit: try decrementing `numduty` or incrementing `numdutfinal` depending on what makes the most sense in this context -- instead of decrementing `numdutfinal`

Comment: i tried both incrementing numdutfinal and decrementing numduty, and both options return "undefined". :(

Comment: Where are you getting "undefined"? Is it when you're trying to get `subskill[list]`? because if `list` starts as an empty string and then you add 1, and then you add 2, you're going to get the string "12" not the number 3, and 12 is beyond the index bounds of your substring array.

Also, this likely still isn't going to do what you described in your paragraph about what you want to do. If the changing the HTML is outside the loop, you're only going to hit it once.